# angular, ng-zorro: object as tag

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I have a nz-select described https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en#api here which allows users to select multiple members.
What I want is to show a username as tag label, but have the id bound to the model.

```
<nz-select formControlName="member" nzMode="tags" (nzOnSearch)="searchUsers($event)">
    <nz-option *ngFor="let member of searchUsersList" [nzLabel]="member.name" [nzValue]="member._id">
    </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

When the user adds a member via the dropdown, the tag will show the username, but in the model, the id gets added.
When reloading this page/field, it seems that I only can add strings to the model which are also being shown as label then . I cannot add complex objects which contain the string and id and I also don't know how to insert tags otherwise.

Any hints on how to accomplish what I want?
I really don't like the idea of using usernames inside the backend/db but I also don't want to see id`s inside the tags.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. When u select one or more users in your tags u see: (username1), (username2), (username3). when u refresh the page and load the model. u see (id1) (id2) (id3). u want that when the user reload the page see again (username1), (username2), (username3) ?

Comment: exactly yes! the Model only holds the id`s ... when the user adds something, the id gets added (value) but the label is different. It seems, that there is no option to trigger that programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can work.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-select-label-in-value',
  template: `
    <nz-select
      [formControl]="control"
      style="width: 200px;"
      nzMode="tags">
      <nz-option *ngFor="let option of optionList"
       [nzValue]="option.value" 
       [nzLabel]="option.label">
      </nz-option>
    </nz-select>
  `
})
export class NzDemoSelectLabelInValueComponent implements OnInit {

  optionList = [{ label: 'Lucy', value: 1,}, { label: 'Jack', value: 2}];

  control: FormControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.control = this.fb.control([2]);
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-73fp31-simfut?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It works thx! It needs a binding. Unfortunately, it will not work with a Formgroup this way but only with a plain formControl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when u reload the page u Destroy all tags. when u load the model and the value is pased to the nz-select the options of these ids is not in your `searchUsersList` atribute. when u reload the page u need get the ids of your form control `member` and hydrate your searchUsersList with these objects. Maybe make a http request to the backend with those ids and get the options of those ids